# How to change value in the select option of an array in the Yii2 view?

Tags: arrays, view, yii2

I use Yii2 Framework and I have this array filter for the 'Ordine' column:

```
[
              'attribute' => 'Ordine',
              'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
              'filter' => ArrayHelper::map($ordine_nome,'id','ordine'),
              'filterWidgetOptions'=>['pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true]],
              'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Tutti...'],
              'label' => "Ordine",
              'width' => '2%',
              
            ],
```

Now, the array is built in this manner:

```
$ordini=Elenchi::find()->asArray()->orderby(['Ordine' => SORT_ASC])->all();
foreach($ordini as $l){
  $ordine_nome[] = ['id'=>$l['Ordine'],'ordine'=>$l['Ordine']];
}
```

It's all ok. But now I want to change the value in the array select option. For example, if the value is 'OFMCap', in the array selection I want to show 'OFMCap - Ordo fratrum minorum capuccinorum'. At the moment the various selection shows only the acronim (for example OFMCap, etc....)

Anyone can help me to build this type of search?
Thank you very much, I hope to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped the same column for id and description

assuming your Elenchi models contains at least two column  ordine and description
with values :

```
ordine      description
-----       -----------
OFMCap,     Ordo fratrum minorum capuccinorum
```

so the find() return the collection of (at least) these two values

```
$ordini=Elenchi::find()->asArray()->orderby(['Ordine' => SORT_ASC])->all();
```

then you should  prepare  you array as

```
foreach($ordini as $l){
    $ordine_nome[] = ['id'=>$l['ordine'],'description'=>$l['description']];
}
```

and you map as

```
'filter' => ArrayHelper::map($ordine_nome,'id','description'),
```

I have use lower case name for db attribure ..  so manage/adapted teh case to your needs

But if you need map directly  .you can wrok on array result for map()

```
$myMap = ArrayHelper::map($ordine_nome,'id','description'),

$myMap['OFMCap'] = 'OFMCap - Ordo fratrum minorum capuccinorum';
```

'filter' => $myMap,

Comment: Sorry, I have not the column description. I have only the column Ordine, that contains tre acronim OFMCap and other acronim. I want to add in the select option of the array the text for every acronim. For example OFMCap - Ordo fratrum....etc. Is clear now? I hope

Comment: Is not clear  to me .. if you have not the description in the Elenchi Model  then from where you obtain the descriptios?  how you map each ordine entry with a proper description.. ??

Comment: I would to know if is possible to add a text in an option select of an array in the view of a index file. In the index I have the table Elenchi, in this table there is a Grid column called 'Ordine'. In this column, on the head, you can choose the option. I want to add a text in the select options. For example, if a possible selection is 'OFMCap', I want to show 'OFMCap - Order fratrum......'

Comment: yes  ..  you can add  (and change)  value in the map array  .. i have posted  a suggestion .. this work at PHP level otherwise if want chnage dinamically client-side .. you need  javascript

Comment: Great! Sorry, I hasn't seen the suggestion. Is good!!